# Lexical Editor: DecoratorNode in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, class, extend, lexicaljs

How do you handle decorator node output in vanilla js? It looks like the decorate method of thevDecoratorNode Class is for rendering React components. Is the decorate() method required to extend the DecoratorNode in vanilla js. The exact reason for the DecoratorNode is not very clear.

Example - How would you implement the below in vanilla js?

```
class HorizontalRuleNode extends lexical.DecoratorNode {
  static getType() {
    return 'horizontalrule';
  }
  static clone(node) {
    return new HorizontalRuleNode(node.__key);
  }
  static importJSON(serializedNode) {
    return $createHorizontalRuleNode();
  }
  static importDOM() {
    return {
      hr: () => ({
        conversion: convertHorizontalRuleElement,
        priority: 0
      })
    };
  }
  exportJSON() {
    return {
      type: 'horizontalrule',
      version: 1
    };
  }
  exportDOM() {
    return {
      element: document.createElement('hr')
    };
  }
  createDOM() {
    return document.createElement('hr');
  }
  getTextContent() {
    return '\n';
  }
  isInline() {
    return false;
  }
  updateDOM() {
    return false;
  }
  decorate() {
    return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(HorizontalRuleComponent, {
      nodeKey: this.__key
    });
  }
}type here
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Javascript forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.